transfer to a wallet while deploying a smart contract
I want to know how to transfer for example 1$ to my address when deploying a smart contract with ethers js v6 here is my code :
const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum)
const signer = await provider.getSigner();
const factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi,bytecode,signer);
 await signer.sendTransaction({
   to: address,
   value: ethers.parseEther("0.0001"),
   gasPrice: gasPrice,
   gasLimit: 21000,
   nonce: nonce
});
const deployedContract = await factory.deploy();

I expect to receive 1 usdt to my wallet while deploying the smart contract with ContractFactory

Can you explain a bit more? These are two different operations and the implementation completely depends on your use case.

I wanted to take a fee from the user before deploying the smart contract but the main issue that the ethers js creates 2 transaction instead of 1, will edit the post
